# json-ld google structured data test tool image field error

Tags: json, validation, structured-data

i tried to validate the structured data on a site using the google structured site testing tool found here: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

if i use a siple json-ld:

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "name": "test"
}
```

the tool complains, that a value is required for the image field. but i don't even have an image field.

Why am I getting that error?

Comment: That is why it complains, the `image` field is required, so you have to add it.

Comment: thank you very much for the info. but what image should i use? there is no storefront and the logo is used in the special logo field.